# How should i keep class "active" added to the selected link in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap in Masterpages in asp.net application where i am applying this technique but failed many times to achieve what i wanted. Below is the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="Default.aspx"  id="home" runat="server" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.aspx" id="loginLink" runat="server">Login</a></li> 
    <li><a  href="signup.aspx" id="signUpLink" runat="server">Sign up</a></li>
    <li><a href="products.aspx" id="productsLink" runat="server">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="AboutUs.aspx" id="aboutUsLink" runat="server">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="ContactUs.aspx" id="contactUsLink" runat="server">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the script:

```
$(function () {
     $('ul li a').on('click', function () {
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Problem is whenever i clicks on any link "active" class remains added to that link but 
when page is completed loaded "active" class is set to the "Home" page??? Plzz help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't use click event because when you click it, you will open deferent page.

Try to give each `<li>` element an id of the file name minus the file extention. (link to index.asp should be id="index")

When a page is opened .NET will pass the id which should be highlighted to jQuery.

jQuery will then assign the class to the correct `<li>` using the id filled in by .NET.
The list should look like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li id="Default"><a href="Default.aspx" runat="server" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
    <li id="login"><a href="login.aspx" runat="server">Login</a></li> 
    <li id="signup"><a  href="signup.aspx" runat="server">Sign up</a</li>
    <li id="products"><a href="products.aspx" runat="server">Products</a></li>
    <li id="aboutUs"><a href="AboutUs.aspx" runat="server">About Us</a></li>
    <li id="contactUs"><a href="ContactUs.aspx" runat="server">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#<%= System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath).ToLower()%>').addClass( "active" );
</script>
```